# How do I take a count in one aggregation pipeline stage and use it in a later stage?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In the final stage of an aggregation pipeline, I want to return a "total count" from an early stage. After an `$unwind` the pipeline filters out documents that I don't want to return to the user. In addition to returning the relevant documents I want to return the "total, unfiltered" count. How do I do that?

It's like I want a stage (near the start of the pipeline) that does nothing but set a variable -- a count of the documents at that stage. Then in my final stage I'd ideally like to reference that variable so I can add "totalUnfiltered": {count value} to the `$project`.

The only thing that looks relevant in the documentation is the `$let` expression. But I think that's only for setting a variable for use in the current stage.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using `$facet` which lets you break a stage into parts, each part corresponding to a list of stages.